# Finding largest value for which $T$ maps $X$ into $X$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X_l = \{f \in C([0,l], \mathbf{R}), 0 \leq f(X) \leq 2, \forall x \in [0,l]\}$ and let $T: X \rightarrow C([0,l], \mathbf{R})$ be defined by $(T(f))(x) = \int_0^{x} f(t)dt$

The question is to find the largest number $l_0$ such that $T$ maps $X_{l_0}$ into $X_{l_0}$.  My first guess is that $l_0 = 1$ but I'm not sure how to go about showing that.

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose $T$ maps $X_l$ into $X_l$ then for any function $f\in X_l$, its image $T(f)$ must also be an element of $X_l$, i.e. with codomain in the interval $[0,2]$. For the lower bound, observe that $T(f)$ is non-negative because $f$ is non-negative.

For the upper bound let us consider the maximal function in $X_l$, the constant function defined $f_0(x)=2$ for all $x\in[0,l]$. Consider its image under $T$:

$$\Big(T(f_0)\Big)(x)=\int_0^x 2dt = 2x\quad\forall x\in[0,l]$$

In particular, for $x=l$, we have $(T(f_0))(l)=2l$. If we insist that $T(f_0)$ is an element of $X_l$, we must have $2l\leq 2$, i.e. $l\leq 1$.

Now it suffices to show that $l=1$ is indeed a solution. Let $f$ be any continuous function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,2]$. Then for all $x\in[0,1]$ we have the following chain of inequalities:

$$\Big(T(f)\Big)(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt\leq\int_0^1 f(t)dt\leq\int_0^1 2dt=2$$

Thus $T(f)\in X_l$ and we have that $l_0=1$ is the maximum value of $l$ for which $T(X_l)\subseteq X_l$.